How to wrap text like this in flutter?
So i recently played with flutter and a concept of wrapping text came to my mind and i'm curious to know about this.
enter image description here
I've tried with Flexiblefor the text, and Sizedbox, or even Expanded, but this is my result instead:
enter image description here
Thanks!

You can use RichText to achieve it
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      const TextSpan(text: "How to do ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      WidgetSpan(child: Container(color: Colors.grey, child: const Text("Icon"))),
      const TextSpan(text: "\nthis in flutter?", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    ],
  ),
),



Sadly that's not flexible and i have to measure the length of the first text and set the limit character first to make it flexible, but thank you for your answer duy tran!

Can you explain more details about what is flexible you meaning here?
